# Trouble with Python file I/O and lists

Tags: python, list, io

So I have to do a Python programming assignment with lists and input and output files and I am stuck. I have to look up triangles with a name, color, and perimeter. The triangles are in a .txt file that looks like this:

```
Triangle1,red,0,0,0,1,1,0
Triangle2,blue,1,0,0,1,0,0
GeorgeJetson,BLUE,20.1,10.5,23,5,6,33.3
Triangle4,BlUe,10,10,20,20,0,0
Triangle2,red,1,1,0,1,0,0
Gusty,orange,0,0,0,2,2,2
Gusty,red,0,0,0,2,2,2
triangle2,orange,0,0,0,2,2,2
```

My code thus far is this:

```
from math import sqrt

def peri(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    side1 = sqrt(((x1-x2)**2)+((y1-y2)**2))
    side2 = sqrt(((x2-x3)**2)+((y2-y3)**2))
    side3 = sqrt(((x1-x3)**2)+((y1-y3)**2))
    p = side1 + side2 + side3
    return p

def main():
    # Handshake
    print("This program performs database processing.")
    # Prompt for input and output file names
    infileName = input("Enter input file name: ")
    outfileName = input("Enter output file name: ")

    # Open input file name and read it
    infile = open(infileName,"r")

    # Read file, create triangle list
    trilist = []
    for line in infile:
        name,color,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 = line.split(",")
        x1 = eval(x1)
        y1 = eval(y1)
        x2 = eval(x2)
        y2 = eval(y2)
        x3 = eval(x3)
        y3 = eval(y3)
        perimeter = peri(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
        triangle = name,color,perimeter
        trilist.append(triangle)

    # Close input file
    infile.close()

    LowerCaseOutfile = False
    AscendingOutfile = False
    print("")
    print("Commands:")
    print("perimeterbyname: Display triangle perimenters by name")
    print("perimeterbycolor: Display triangle perimenters by color")
    print("namebycolor: Display triangle names by color")
    print("colorbyname: Display triangle colors by name")
    print("lowercase: Display triangle names and colors in lowercase")
    print("ascending: Display triangle perimeters in ascending order")
    print("quit: Quit the program")
    print("")
    userInput = input("Enter a command: ")
    while userInput != "quit":
        if userInput == "perimeterbyname":
            triname = input("Enter a triangle name: ")
            for triangle in trilist:
                if triname == name:
                    print(triangle)
                else:
                    print("Invalid name")

        print("")
        print("Commands:")
        print("perimeterbyname: Display triangle perimenters by name")
        print("perimeterbycolor: Display triangle perimenters by color")
        print("namebycolor: Display triangle names by color")
        print("colorbyname: Display triangle colors by name")
        print("lowercase: Display triangle names and colors in lowercase")
        print("ascending: Display triangle perimeters in lascending order")
        print("quit: Quit the program")
        print("")
        userInput = input("Enter a command: ")


    # Open output file name and write it
    outfile = open(outfileName, "w")

    # Write to the output file
    print(trilist, file = outfile)

    # Close output file
    outfile.close()

    print("Triangles have been written to", outfileName)


main()
```

I am having trouble getting the name of the triangle from the list in the if statement. Python does not recognize the variable "name". Help?

Comment: It's a lot easier to debug if you provide the full error output of your code.

Comment: That's a lot of code! Can you boil it down to a few lines? Python likely told you the exact line with the problem, post that stack trace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about while in the loop to print out a triangle only if it matches the user input. The reason that "name" isn't valid there is that python doesn't store what variables you used when creating the list of triangles, only their value. Thus, when you're reading them out again, it's just a value.

So, each trilist (which is a list of tuples) is:
[("name","color",perimeter),("name","color",perimeter)] where "name", "color" and perimeter are the actual values of each triangle.

Now you can do either pull out the values of the tuple into separate variables:

```
name, color, perimeter = triangle
```

inside your for loop and then use the variables as you'd expect or just manually index the tuple directly:

```
name = triangle[0]
```

Now, to bring that together, you can actually write your for loop in two ways:

```
        # leave triangle as a tuple
        for triangle in trilist:
            if triname == triangle[0]:
                print(triangle)
            else:
                print("Invalid name")
```

or:

```
        # assign elements of tuple to separate variables
        for name,color,perimeter in trilist:
            if triname == name:
                print(triangle)
            else:
                print("Invalid name")
```